# Custom FindBugs check, to detect method call & variables in Scope

Tags: java, findbugs

I'm looking to write a custom FindBugs detector to do the following:

- Look for specific method calls
- Look for Objects in Scope implementing a specific interface

Using these two my custom detector would report errors when the wrong version of a method was being called.

For example:

I have **Logger.info(String)** & **Logger.info(String, Context)** methods. I want to use the above to detect calls to Logger.info(String), then look for the presence of an Object implementing the Context interface in Scope (i.e. Local Var, Class Var, Inherited Class Var or Method Parameter) and then report that as an error, saying that the 2nd method should be called instead.

So, it appears I'll be able to do the first part using INVOKESPECIAL, so should not be too difficult. But does anyone know I'd go about the 2nd part ?

Thanks a lot,
Ro